# Proving of exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, exponential-sum

If $3^a=21^b$ and $7^c=21^b$
 prove that $b=\frac{ac}{(a+c)}$

Can someone please help me prove this ? 
Already tried: 
$3^a=3^b \times 7^b$ and $7^c=3^b \times 7^b$ 
Also, $3^a=7^b$.

Comment: Hint: instead of proving that $ b = \frac{ac}{a+c}$, consider proving that $$3^b = 3^\frac{ac}{a+c}$$ or even that $$3^{b(a+c)} = 3^{ac}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong, of course. Try $a=b=c=0$.

For $abc\neq0$ we obtain:

$3^{ac}=21^{bc}$ and $7^{ac}=21^{ab}$.

Thus, $$21^{ac}=21^{bc+ab}$$ or $$ac=ab+bc$$ or
$$b=\frac{ac}{a+c}$$ and we are done!

Comment: Good point about it being wrong. I think all that you need is that $a+c \ne 0$, however.

Comment: @John Hughes Easy to show that if $a+c=0$ then $a=c=b=0$. Indeed, if $a+c=0$ then $3^a=7^{-a}$, which gives $a=0$ and $a=b=c=0$. Thus, it's  enough $abc\neq0$.

Comment: You're right of course: in the context of this problem, it does imply that.  I just thought that $a+c = 0$ appears to be a weaker initial assumption (involves fewer of the unknowns) and easier (for me!) to parse.

Answer (score 1):

from the first, You have

$$3=(21)^{\frac {b}{a}} $$
and from the second,

$$7=(21 )^{\frac {b}{c} }$$
thus by product,

$$21=(21)^{\frac {b}{a}+\frac {b}{c}} $$

hence

$$1=\frac {b}{a}+\frac {b}{c} $$
and

$$\frac {1}{b}=\frac {1}{a}+\frac {1}{c} $$

$$\implies b=\frac {ac}{a+c} $$